# UML - Use case scenarios & data dictionaries

Tags: documentation, uml, analysis, use-case, requirements

I am currently working for a company writing use cases.  They have a template which mixes them with data dictionaries.  I've never seen this kind of template. I searched the web looking for answers. I am wondering if this is a correct practice/method. If it is, does this template have an specific name? They are calling it use case template, I do think is wrong to call it that way.

This is an example: 
**Note:** This template has a valid use case written above of it (not shown in here).

**Step:**  1 
**Actor:** Application 
**Action:** 
Display login page

Login page section has the following fields:
- Username
- Password
- Submit button

Here's the description of the fields for this section:
- Username - textbox field, required, no default value, allow 10 character maximum

- Password - textbox field, required, no default value, allow alphanumeric characters, allow a maximum of 30 characters

**Step:**  2 
**Actor:** User 
**Action:**
User enters username & password
User hits submit button

**Step:**  3 
**Actor:**  Application 
**Action:** 
The app allows access to the page.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by data dictionaries in this context, but I tried an answer anyways.

Comment: These steps are usually called essential steps and are intended to refine the use case in order to derive activies from it.

Answer (score 2):

This is common practice. I don't know if he's the inventor, but [Alistair Cockburn](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQ6qnB1LTNAhUC7BQKHWf-AXYQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Falistair.cockburn.us%2Fget%2F2465&usg=AFQjCNGpt5HE7QnfEl4At6DObwU6HoC-wg&sig2=sMax8ZYy6L2UO_u9PyS-Tg) provides such templates along with rules how to fill them in.

However, for the methodological approach and much of the background info needed in use case synthesis I always recommend [Bittner/Spence](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihieHs1bTNAhUBshQKHcNPANcQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbooks.google.com%2Fbooks%3Fid%3DzvxfXvEcQjUC&usg=AFQjCNH1iMmtLjKSy4xSQXDGSUz0Wa5YsA&sig2=MxIzgWTRjyBiqgPg5k10Lg). (Note: there is a Word-version of this book when you google for it. I have not idea now this infringes copyrights, but the money for the book is worth it.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've seen this before, but it is not common practice to specify the data requirements in such detail in the use case scenario. In fact, in your example, they are even trying to describe the user interface details in words.

I would recommend, like you expect, to have a separate data model (which is a bit more than just a data dictionary) and specify the data requirements over there. For the user interface, it would be better to create a prototype or wireframe. Too often, IT departments tend to create their own methodologies instead of buying a good book.